# Codeigniter email pane paste a picture

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter, email

May I ask if is it posible to paste a picture on a email pane using codeigniter framework so that when the user receives the email its like embedded on the mail and no need to download the picture like on outlook .

And if it is, please share how can I do that . 
Thanks !

Here's the screenshot of my email pane and I cannot paste picture .

[image]

Comment: add some code as well

Comment: is it possible ? to just ctrl+v the picture .

Comment: You have to convert image to base64 string and use that string in img tag to display image.

Comment: I tried that also but still I need to download pictures on outlook.
Here's my `code:
$path = 'i.png';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

$message = '<p>This should display an image:<img src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/bWNWz.png"><img src="'.$base64.'"> </p> <a href="http://localhost:1000/eTraining/">Join Us Here!</a>';
`